# PHP-CODEIGNITER how to get data in session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I want echo my list of trip, when I try print_r the value can show but when I echo the result always

> Message: Undefined variable: adventure
>
> Filename: views/profile.php
>
> Line Number: 121
>
> Backtrace:
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: views/profile.php
>
> Line Number: 121

this is my controller :

```
 public function getListTrip(){         
    $this->load->model('userModel');        
    $data['adventure'] = $this->userModel->getTrip()->result_array();
    //echo ($data);
    $this->load->view('profile', $data);        
 }
```

and this is my model :

```
function getTrip(){
    $userId = $this->session->userdata('user_id');    
    return $this->db->get_where('adventure',['user_id' => $userId]);
}
```

this is my view

```
                        <table>
                           <?php
                            foreach ($adventure as $b){
                                echo "<tr>
                                <td>$b->name</td>
                                <td>$b->place</td>
                                <td>$b->category</td>

                                </tr>";
                            }

                        ?>
                        </table>
```

so how should I edit my code to make the value show in my page whit **echo** or **foreach** not in print_r... thanks a lot

Comment: Tip You are naming your controllers wrong for CI please read here for about file and class naming in CI https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your model

```
function getTrip(){
    $userId = $this->session->userdata('user_id');    
    $query= $this->db->get_where('adventure',['user_id' => $userId]);
    return $query->result();
}
```

Also chnage in your controller

```
$data['adventure'] = $this->userModel->getTrip()->result_array();
```

To

```
$data['adventure'] = $this->userModel->getTrip();
```

Comment: its work dude, thanks.. but I should see this in view of my controller /getListTrip cannot see in my /profile

Answer (score 1):

`echo` is used to output one or more strings, since your `$data` is an array you see the error,  you need to pass data to view and iterate it in the view itself, like:

```
public function getListTrip(){
    $this->load->model('userModel');
    $data['adventure'] = $this->userModel->getTrip()->result_array();
    //pass data to your view
    $this->load->view('yourviewname', $data);
}
```

For more information check [Codeigniter Views](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view)

**Update**

Check if your array is not empty before trying to iterate thru it, like in your view::

```
<?php
if( !empty($adventure) ) {
    foreach($adventure as $b):
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $b['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $b['place']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $b['category']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    endforeach;
}
?>
```

Comment: I try what your suggest, and still got some error in my view page, please help me where is my error??

Comment: @FahmiSalmin check the added code. Btw, since the reult is array, you cannot access the fields with '->' operator.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot echo the content of an Array.

So whenever you want to view the Content of an array use `print_r($arrayName);`

And When you just want to print any variable just use `echo $variableName;`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with your code. If you're not using autoloader to load the **session library** that might be your issue:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

You can check the documentation [Codeigniter sessions](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html)